# Set JAVA_HOME to Open JDK11 in Eclipse in Gradle JVM without disturbing System Env Variables

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, gradlew

I am working in a PoC that would require me to run a `Spring Boot` project (developed for Java-8) in Compatibility mode pointing `JAVA_HOME` to `Open JDK-11`.

This is perfectly working fine when I build and run the project from the `command-prompt` where I can set `JAVA_HOME` manually before executing gradle tasks.

This is perfectly working fine, when I import the project in to my `IntelliJ` and there i get an option to set `JAVA_HOME` ..

Now my text task is to prove the same by importing the project in to `Eclipse-Oxygen` .. Am not sure where exactly i should point `eclipse` to `JAVA_HOME`.. It is also looking for `JRE_HOME` .. But it should take everything from `gradlew.bat`

`Gradle-JVM` is automatically picked-up in Eclipse from the `gradle-wrapper (gradlew.bat`). In `gradlew.bat` the `JAVA_HOME` is taken from the System's `Environments`. This can be overriden in `Intellij` where it provides us an option to set an `gradle-JVM`. I wanted to understand how a similar thing can be done in `Eclipse`

Help please !

Answer (score 2):

You can set your own JAVA_HOME by following below…

Go to Gradle Task in Eclipse.
Right click on which gradle task you need to run and select “Open gradle run configurations”
Then go to JAVA_HOME tab.
Browse to JDK that you want to use.
Then apply…

Thats it, it should help…

Answer (score 1):

You can configure environment variables in the run config of your project. On the Environment tab, you can extend or replace the default environment.

[image: On the environment tab.]

Comment: It is not working .. The `JRE` in the `JRE Tab` (in the above screen shot) was still pointing to `JRE-8` in my local desktop .. I removed that .. Because i want everything to be booted from the `java.exe` inside my `Open JDK-11` path

Comment: while importing the `gradle` project in Eclipse, it is taking the default `JAVA_HOME` set in my laptop and doesn't give me an option to choose my `JAVA_HOME` for Gradle